# Is there any way to create a new page in the Flutter web app and admin panel (Laravel Framework)?

Tags: laravel, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, flutter-web

I have purchased a Flutter-based full source code for a food delivery android app (user app, web app and delivery man app) and admin panel built with Laravel Framework for a project of mine.

As per the author's documentation guide, I have customized the food app as per my business needs.

I need help with creating a page. In the app I have 4 pages, I want 2 pages more.

I have created a new page in directories

`public_html/admin.domain.in/resources/views/refund-policy.blade.php`
`public_html/admin.domain.in/resources/views/admin-views/business-settings/refund-policy.blade.php`

also added below code in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('refund-policy', 'HomeController@refund_policy')->name('refund-policy');
```

and `routes/admin.php`

```
Route::get('refund-policy', 'BusinessSettingsController@refund_policy')->name('refund-policy')->middleware('actch');
Route::post('refund-policy', 'BusinessSettingsController@refund_policy_update')->middleware('actch');
```

But I am unable to see a new page section in the admin panel and website.

Answer (score 0):

create controller and function like this

```
class HomeController 
{
 public function refund_policy()
 {
  return view('refund-policy');
  }
}
```

Then add menu on side menu